# Changing background color using ngClass and boolean is not working correctly?

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

I am trying to check an object coming in a back-end response to see if error.isCritical is true or false and setting the ngClass accordingly, i've tried many different approaches, but this is the one i am using right now:

Angular/HTML:

```
<p-table>
    <ng-template pTemplate="header">
        <tr *ngFor="let error of errors" 
            [ngClass]="{critical: error.isCritical, notCritical: 
            !error.isCritical}">
             <td width="25%">
                {{ error.dateRange['start'] }} to
                {{ error.dateRange['end'] }}
             </td>
             <td width="25%">{{ error.processId }}</td>
             <td width="50%">{{ error.message }}</td>
        </tr>
     </ng-template>
</p-table>
```

CSS:

```
.critical{
  background-color: red;
}
.notCritical{
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 5px;
  color: black;
}
```

It seems to either make them all red background, or all white background no matter what i try, and i have checked the backend call and the isCritical flag is false for some and true for others, so i can't figure out why they are all red when they are red?

Any Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `[ngClass]="error.isCritical ? 'critical' : 'notCritical'"` unless your `error.isCritical` isn't actually supplying the proper truthey/falsey/bool. Would need a reproducible example to confirm.

Comment: This might seem like a silly comment, but never hurts to check: it looks like your `error` is an object in some array you're iterating over, so make sure that you're not actually displaying the *same* object over and over.

Comment: I am not displaying the same object over again, i even added a <td> entry inside every row that shows the current isCritical value for that error and even the entries that said false are displaying red, so apparently my ngClass statement is not accessing the correct error, because it is displaying red for all entries whether true or false... I am stuck at the moment

Answer (score 1):

Replace your code with below code:

```
<p-table>
    <ng-template pTemplate="header">
        <tr *ngFor="let error of errors" 
   [ngClass]="[error.isCritical ? 'critical' : 'notCritical']">
             <td width="25%">
                {{ error.dateRange['start'] }} to
                {{ error.dateRange['end'] }}
             </td>
             <td width="25%">{{ error.processId }}</td>
             <td width="50%">{{ error.message }}</td>
        </tr>
     </ng-template>
</p-table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can dynamically add classes using the code below:

```
[ngClass]="{'critical': error.isCritical, 'notCritical' : !error.isCritical }"
```

Comment: Yes thank you for your answer Leon, i have actually used this exact code before and just tried it again and for some reason it has access to the wrong error object or something because it is still displaying error.isCritical table rows as red, in fact if error.isCritical is true OR false they are being displayed red,.  I am still working on this but i think it has less to do with the ngClass directive and more to do with why the wrong error object and error.isCritical is being considered inside the ngClass statement...

Answer (score 0):

you can try different syntax (Angular 2+)

type one

```
[class.my_class] = "step === 'step1'"
```

type two

```
[ngClass]="{'my_class': step === 'step1'}"
```

and multiple option:

```
[ngClass]="{'my_class': step === 'step1', 'my_class2' : step === 'step2' }"
```

type three

```
[ngClass]="{1 : 'my_class1', 2 : 'my_class2', 3 : 'my_class4'}[step]"
```

type four

```
[ngClass]="step == 'step1' ? 'my_class1' : 'my_class2'"
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but just making sure i understand, it all of your examples, is step and expression? like a boolean expression that can be either true or false?